# Passing flatlist component key as a parameter

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

```
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,FlatList,TouchableOpacity,Dimensions,AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {Font, LinearGradient} from "expo";
const data = [
  { key: 'Addition'  }, { key: 'B' }, { key: 'C'  },{ key: 'D'},
  { key: 'E'  },{ key: 'F'  }
];

const numColumns = 1;
export default class GScreen extends React.Component {
  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
          colors={['#2c81af','#92ede8']}
          style={styles.contcontainer}
          >
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={(item) =>{this.props.navigation.navigate('AScreen', {content : 'Addition' });}}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.key}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        numColumns={numColumns}
      />
    );
  };
}
```

For each component of thiis flatlist , I want to pass {item.key} as a parameter when we navigate to AScreen instead of 'Addition'(Or any single value).How can i achieve this?

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('AScreen', {content : item.key})`

Comment: @SiSa It is returnig empty  object when i pass item.key

Comment: @notnotparas check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the passing of the object but of how you have constructed your `onPress` function in your `TouchableOpacity`

Currently this is what you have:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={(item) =>{this.props.navigation.navigate('AScreen', {content : 'Addition' });}}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>{item.key}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Notice that in your `onPress` function you have `(item) => {...}` The word `item` inside the function is overwriting the value that you have for `item`. That is why you are getting `undefined`. All you need to do is remove the word `item` from the function call.

If you change your code to the following then it should pass the value as expected

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() =>{this.props.navigation.navigate('AScreen', {content : item.key });}}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>{item.key}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Notice that the `onPress` is now `() => {...}`. This should stop the value for `item` from being overwritten